# How to access a list containing specific item in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of list like below:

```
dict = {'key1':list1, 'key2':list2}
```

and

```
list1=['a', 'b', 'c']
list2=['d', 'e', 'f']
```

i.e.,

```
dict = {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2': ['d', 'e', 'f']}
```

I would like to get the object of the list containing 'b', that is list1, using map rather than using an explicit for loop. I googled a lot but can't find relate information. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, it's a bad idea to call a dictionary `dict`. Once you do that, you can no longer access the builtin type and constructor of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no way to do this without an explicit or implicit loop.

That is, you can do one of these:

```
key = next(lst for lst in d.values() if 'b' in lst)
```

But either way, that's really doing the same thing a for loop does. In particular, it's roughly the same as this:

```
for lst in d.values():
    if 'b' in lst:
        key = let
        break
```

… which is probably exactly the loop you were going to write.

---

However, if you're going to do this multiple times, you can just do a for loop once to build an appropriate data structure, then you can just do a quick lookup each time.

For example, let's build a map from each list member to the list it's in:

```
valmap = {val:lst for lst in d.values() for val in lst}
```

Now, every time you want to find out which list `'b'` is in, just do this:

```
valmap['b']
```

---

From your question, you may have been asking about using `map`. First, `map` is still just an implicit `for` loop. Second, `map` doesn't really give you any way to do what you want; you could use it to, e.g., create a new sequence with a True in place of the list containing `'b'` and a `False` everywhere else, but then you still have to search that sequence to find the `True`. What you want here is `filter`. You could write the genexpr solution above as:

```
key = next(filter(lambda lst: 'b' in lst, d.values()))
```

And that's pretty much exactly the same thing as the genexpr. (In CPython, it's probably a bit faster than the explicit loop and a bit slower than the genexpr, but that also probably doesn't matter at all.)

Comment: +1 for, `There's really no way to do this without an explicit or implicit loop.`

Comment: @johnthexiii: Actually, I don't really like the way I wrote it. The for loop in a genexpr/comp is pretty explicit—it's even spelled the same way as in a statement. But I'm not sure how else to make the distinction in a novice-friendly way…

Answer (score 0):

```
next(x for x in D.itervalues() if 'b' in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong data structure if you need to look things up by value like that. For that, you should build an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) that maps values to the keys that correspond to them. (You can build this inverted index up as you build up your dictionary.) Once you have that key, you can easily lookup the containing list in the original dictionary. If for some reason you can't build up the inverted index as you build the dictionary (maybe because you're not building it, it's just delivered to you), you can build the inverted index like this:

```
inverted_index = {v : k for k, l in d.items() for v in l}
```

Here, I'm using `d` for the name of your dictionary instead of `dict` since `dict` is the name of the built in type which you should never hide.

Comment: First, his dict values are lists, so this won't work. (You can't use a list as a dict key.) And, even if it did work, it wouldn't solve his problem, which is to look things up by any individual element of each list, rather than by the list itself.

Comment: @abamert: Nope. If you enter these lines into interactive mode `>>> d = {'key1' : ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2' : ['d', 'e', 'f']}
>>> inverted_index = {v : k for k, l in d.items() for v in l}
>>> print inverted_index` you'll see the output `{'a': 'key1', 'b': 'key1', 'c': 'key1', 'd': 'key2', 'e': 'key2', 'f': 'key2'}` which then lets you look up the key via `>>> inverted_index['b']` which will produce `key1` and the list via `>>> d[inverted_index['b']]` which will produce `['a', 'b', 'c']`. That is, *exactly* what he wanted. So, it *does* work, and it *does* solve his problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the extra `for v in l` at the end. You're right. But it's still mapping to the keys, not the lists that he asked for, which is why you need the extra step `d[inverted_index['b']]` instead of just `inverted_dict['b']`. If he actually needs the keys, that's an advantage; if he doesn't, it's just extra complexity for no reason.

Comment: @abamert: Extra complexity? It's *trivial* to use what I provided to build it whichever way he needs it. You can remove the down vote?

Comment: SO doesn't allow removing downvotes unless the answer is edited. I found something trivial to edit in your answer so I could do so. Anyway, I don't think double-indexing is necessarily trivial to someone who doesn't even know how to approach this problem in the first place…

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks. By the way, that's exactly why I raised the concept of *inverted index* and provided a link to an explanatory page for the OP. The OP didn't even know what to Google for; now they do.